# How to autorun a piece of software from a CD/DVD on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cd, autorun, dvd

I want my software to run automatically from a CD/DVD with no user interaction whenever the user puts the CD/DVD into the drive. As far as I know autorun should still work with Windows 7, they just forbid it for USB drives.

But how?

Let's say I want to start my software xy.exe, what do I have to put inside my autorun.inf? I tried this but it's not working:

```
[AutoRun]
open=xy.exe
```

Is there anything else to do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See MS' official Autorun documentation at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144202(v=vs.85).aspx

Your `autorun.inf` example looks OK to me - if you are testing on Windows 7 then I would expect you to see the "AutoPlay" Window when you insert the CD, with `xy.exe` as an option, above "open folder to view files".

If you get no pop up at all then try right-clicking on the disc in My Computer and selecting AutoPlay in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to pass an argument to the program to be auto played:

```
[autorun]
open=myprogram.exe /argument
```